# Unable to boot kernel and rootfile system in Qemu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu

I am using ts-4900 freescale board. I am not able to boot the kernel and rootfile system (initrd) in Qemu. I did the following kernel configuration steps.

1. export the cross compiler parth
2. export LOADADDR=0x10008000
3. make esse_defconfig
4. make menuconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
5. make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- uImage

The image is in `/arch/arm/boot/uImage`, and and I have working rootfile system (initrd).

Now i am trying to boot in Qemu using bellow step.

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -kernel uImage -initrd /home/mahesh/mahesh/ts_4900/initrd.
```

then the error.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I answered the copy of this question on the unix & linux stack exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411521/unable-to-boot-kernel-and-rootfile-system-in-qemu